# Селектор точного вхождения текста

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Есть код на странице:

```
<span class="price">101 200 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
<span class="price">0 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
<span class="price">500 100 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
<span class="price">10 899 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
<span class="price">23 200 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
<span class="price">13 213 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
```

мне нужно как-то через jquery поменять текст

```
<span class="price">0 <span class="currency">руб</span></span>
```

на

```
<span class="price">По<span class="currency">согласованию</span></span>
```

Вот таким селектором получилось выделить то, что нужно:

```
span.price:contains("0") span.currency'
```

но JQ выделяет не только там, где 0 руб., но  и там, где 0 присутствует, например, селектор сработает на 100 399 руб. и на 10  рублей.

А мне нужно, чтобы он срабатывал только на 0 руб.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ufaclub](/users/23331/ufaclub), селектор `:contains` не обладает нужным вам функционалом.
Воспользуйтесь функцией [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).
С ее помощью вы сможете написать свои правила для фильтрации dom элементов.
Внутри нее с помощью функции [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) вы можете проверить, есть ли у `.price` потомок `.currency`

```
$('.price').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "0 руб" && $(this).has('.currency');
});
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/a9rcdn3b/)**